# How to run a command on heroku console from a rake task and know when it finishes

Tags: ruby, bash, heroku, rake

I have a rake task like below. However, after the first system line runs and User.find_each(&:save) finishes the heroku console stays open and the ruby script does not proceed to the next system call as the first one is not "finished". How do I exit out of the first system call (and proceed to the next) after the User records are done saving?

```
task :production do
  Bundler.with_clean_env do
    system("echo 'User.find_each(&:save)' | heroku run console --remote production")
    system("echo 'Post.find_each(&:save)' | heroku run console --remote production")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running something (`rails console`) that doesn't terminate.

What happens when you run `rails console` locally?  It won't terminate until you type `exit'.

So try this:

echo 'User.find...; exit' | heroku run console

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there any way to chain multiple actions in the console without exiting each time to save on the overhead of having to enter and exit between each step? For example, entering the console, running both the User and Post steps above and then exiting?

Comment: What would you do locally?  I imagine: commandA; commandB; commandC will work.